# Javascript dropdown issue

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

i have this 4 dropdown menu, i will use to set an advanced search on my site. I'm not a javascript programmer, so i will need an help to semplify the code. I splitted the code 4 time for my 4 field, but i have an error, a variable overwrite the other 3 setted before. There is for sure a easy easy way to do what i need with half of the code. Here's my enviroment http://jsfiddle.net/4K7L7/3/

```
    function DropDown(el) {
        this.dd = el;
        this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
        this.opts = this.dd.find('ul.dropdown > li');
        this.val = '';
        this.index = -1;
        this.initEvents();
    }
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            return false;
        });

        obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text('Tipo: ' + obj.val);
        });
    },
    getValue : function() {
        return this.val;
    },
    getIndex : function() {
        return this.index;
    }
}

$(function() {

    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-1').removeClass('active');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems ok. You just need to create an instance for each of your elements, like this:

```
var dd = new DropDown($('#dd')),
    cc = new DropDown($('#cc')),
    bb = new DropDown($('#bb')),
    aa = new DropDown($('#aa'));
```

Or add a "dd" class to all your elements and then you can have:

```
$('.dd').each(function(){
  new DropDown($(this));
});
```

No need to duplicate the function...

Comment: I need i think to set the variables because, in this section here:

    obj.opts.on('click',function(){
            var opt = $(this);
            obj.val = opt.text();
            obj.index = opt.index();
            obj.placeholder.text('Tipo: ' + obj.val);
        });
i have to specify a different placeholder for every istance of the dropdown. 
Now the last function (the last writed) owerite the previous placeholder. Then everytime i select a dropdown the placeholder set is the last one. You can see better my problem in jsfiddle. You can suggest me the variables way?

Comment: nope, now is the first placehold to owerite the others one. I need a specified placehold for every input :(

Comment: I would like to have 4 different placeholder: "Tipo" is the first one, i click, select a value and i have "tipo: selected value", when i click the second one "regione" i select a value, i would like to have "Regione: selected value". Now the placeholder is "Tipo" for every of the 4 dropdown!

Comment: Ah I see now, try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/PUfD6/ (keep the original span text into a property)

Comment: Thanks man you made my day ^^ How can i learn js like you? ahahah

Comment: If you wrote that function, I'd say you're on the right track ;)